# Getting $\sin^2$ and $\cos^2$ values from $\sin^2 \alpha = \frac{1}{4} \cos^2 \alpha = \frac{1}{4}(1 - \sin^2 \alpha)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How can you get from
$$\sin^2 \alpha = \frac{1}{4} \cos^2 \alpha = \frac{1}{4}(1 - \sin^2 \alpha)$$

to $$\sin^2 \alpha = \frac{1}{5} \\or \\ \cos^2 \alpha = \frac{4}{5}.$$

Sorry, but I can't see that. I'm just starting with trig.

Comment: It's just algebra: think of $\sin^2\alpha$ as a variable $x$ and collect terms. That gives you the first equation. Then use $\cos^2\alpha = 1-\sin^2\alpha$.

Comment: Your problem solved itself in your very first sentence! Could you not see that $\sin^2{\alpha}\quad$ could be replaced with a simpler variable, yielding, say, $m=\frac14·(1-m)\text{?}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the first and third part of the equality:
$$\sin ^2\alpha={1 \over 4}(1-\sin^2 \alpha)\\ \sin ^2\alpha={1\over 4}-{1\over 4}\sin ^2\alpha\\  {5 \over 4}\sin ^2\alpha={1\over 4}\\\sin ^2\alpha={1\over 5} $$

Then just plug it into first and second part of the equality and you'll get the $\cos ^2\alpha$ value.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin^2 \alpha = \frac{1}{4} \cos^2 \alpha\\
\cos^2 \alpha = 1-\sin^2 \alpha\\
\sin^2 \alpha = \frac{1}{4}(1 - \sin^2 \alpha)\\
\sin^2 \alpha = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4}\sin^2 \alpha\\
\sin^2 \alpha + \frac{1}{4}\sin^2 \alpha= \frac{1}{4}\\
\frac{5}{4}\sin^2 \alpha= \frac{1}{4}\\
5\sin^2 \alpha= 1\\
\sin^2 \alpha= \frac15$

$1-\cos^2 \alpha= \frac15\\
\cos^2 \alpha= 1-\frac15\\
\cos^2 \alpha= \frac45$